# Iterating list of lists of objects going not well

Tags: for-loop, unity-game-engine, iteration

I am trying to itarating over a list of lists of gameobjects in Unity3D but it returns me the following error:

> Assets/Scripts/OrganizarTilesEmMatriz.cs(45,18): error CS1525:
>    Unexpected symbol `<', expecting`type'

What's the correct form to write this code:

```
 List<List<GameObject>>tilesOrganizadosPorColuna=new List<List<GameObject>>();

 List<List<GameObject>> organizarTilesEixoY()
        {
             List<List<GameObject>> temporario = new List<List<GameObject>>();
             foreach(<List<GameObject>arraylist in tilesOrganizadosPorColuna){
                 temporario.Add(arraylist.Sort(new CustomComparer());
             }

          return temporario;
        }


        class CustomComparer : IComparer
        {
            Comparer _comparer = new Comparer(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
            public int Compare(object x, object y)
            {
                // Convert string comparisons to int
                return _comparer.Compare(Convert.ToInt32(x), Convert.ToInt32(y));
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 foreach(<List<GameObject>arraylist in tilesOrganizadosPorColuna){
```

Looks wrong, try this instead ...

```
 foreach(List<GameObject> arraylist in tilesOrganizadosPorColuna){
```